# How to Convert varchar Data type to Cassandra Map (Key value pair) conversion in Talend

Tags: oracle, cassandra, talend

I am trying to load `varchar2` Data from Oracle to Cassandra Map data type(key value pair) using a Talend Mapping. I have tried `TConvertType`, `Tdenormalize` and `TJavaFlex` Components to convert such datatype into Map data type but the following error occurs:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

I have also tried `TCassandraOutputBulk` to write insert query but still not resolved.

Is there any way this can be done in Talend?

Comment: Hey Coxe, can you please share a little more about your use case my understanding is that you are trying to map a Varchar2 to a java.util.map so that you can store these as a cassandra object Map why do you want to do that?

Comment: Hi @DillonWright Thanks for the reply! Exactly what it is happening here whenever I tried to convert the data type from string to map using components i got the error and been unable to do so, I want to load data from oracle to key value pair (Map type) in cassandra using talend but I am still finding the way to do that. Can you suggest me what to do regarding type conversion into map type or user defined of (cassandra).